# Why aren't all ticklabels shown on the x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science, pareto-chart

This is my code.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
fig.set_figheight(7)
fig.set_figwidth(12)
ax1.bar(df.index, df['occurence of defects'], color="C0")
ax1.set_ylabel("Qty", color="C0")
ax1.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C0")
ax1.set_xlabel("Defect")
ax1.set_xticklabels(df['Name of Defect'],rotation=45)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index, df["cum percentage"], color="C1", marker="D", ms=7)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C1")
plt.show()
```

this is ss of output
[image]
I made circles where labels are missing. How can I fix that? Even the current labels on the x-axis aren't in their supposed positions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly. A sample input (as text or link to the file) that reproduces your problem will greatly improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details, but it automatically determines the scale of the graph according to the number of ticks. In this case, we are skipping one. Try disabling `#ax1.set_xticklabels(df['Name of Defect'],rotation=45)` and you will understand. If you specify the number of ticks for the axis you need, it will match the label and display.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name of Defect':list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'), 'occurence of defects':np.random.randint(1,10,16)})

df['cum'] = df['occurence of defects'].cumsum()
df.sort_values('occurence of defects', ascending=False, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
df['per'] = df['cum'].apply(lambda x: x / df['cum'].sum())
df['cum percentage'] = df['per'].cumsum()

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
fig.set_figheight(7)
fig.set_figwidth(12)
ax1.bar(df.index, df['occurence of defects'], color="C0")
ax1.set_ylabel("Qty", color="C0")
ax1.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C0")
ax1.set_xlabel("Defect")
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0,16))
ax1.set_xticklabels(df['Name of Defect'],rotation=45)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index, df["cum percentage"], color="C1", marker="D", ms=7)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter())
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", colors="C1")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Matplotlib* has such a characteristics, that when you invoke
*set_xticklabels*, then *set_xticks* should also be invoked (to specify
where these labels are to be placed (at which *x* coordinates)).

In your case *x* labels should be placed below **each** bar, so insert:

```
ax1.set_xticks(df.index)
```

before:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(df['Name of Defect'], rotation=45)
```

The reason is that quite often *x* labels should be placed not at each
*x* coordinate, especially when the plot type is other than *bar*.

And another hint: Since your *x* labels are quite long, consider rotation
of 90, or other, but greater than 45.